# batch script moving multiple file extensions to sub folder passing parameters to a single subroutine

Tags: batch-file, command-line, window, windows-8.1

So, I am trying to code a batch script operation that handles moving certain types of file extensions (photos = .jpg, .png etc) to their respective sub directory.

The problem I am in counter is when I go to run the loop doesn't stop and I can't track if certain types are being looped through.

Is there a way of doing this operation within a single subroutine? Or a better way? Also, if you can leave helpful links as I really would like to understand what I am coding more thoroughly.

I am running Windows 8.1

```
    :cleanup
set Fdocs=%CD%\1_docs
set Fphotos=%CD%\2_photos
set Fdesigns=%CD%\3_designs
set Freviews=%CD%\4_reviews
set Ffinal=%CD%\5_final
set $ext=
set action=Cleaning

:: Create a subroutine function loop : FOR , go through array file extentions and move to destination
:: FOR /F
:fMover
for %%a in (%1) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%2"
echo %%a
timeout 1 >nul

:: CLEAN :: documents
set $ext=.txt .doc .docx .xls .csv .ppt .pptx
call :fMover %$ext% %Fdocs%
cls
echo %action% project folder.


:: CLEAN :: images
set $ext=.jpg .png .tiff .raw .nef .crw .dng
:: for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%Fphotos%"
call :fMover %$ext% %Fphotos%
cls
echo %action% project folder..
timeout 1 >nul


:: CLEAN :: designs
set $ext=.psd .psb
call :fMover %$ext% %Fdesigns%
::for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%Fdesigns%\2_psd"
set $ext=.ai .svg .svgz .esp
call :fMover %$ext% %Fdesigns%
::for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%Fdesigns%\1_ai"
set %ext=.indd .idml 
call :fMover %$ext% %Fdesigns%
::for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%Fdesigns%\3_indd"
cls
echo %action% project folder...
timeout 1 >nul


cls
echo done.
timeout 2 >nul
```

Comment: There is a typo in `:: CLEAN :: designs` section: `set %ext=.indd .idml`.  A correction made in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch *structure* could be as follows (you should skip over predefined subroutine and properly return from it):

```
    :cleanup
set "Fdocs=%CD%\1_docs"
set "Fphotos=%CD%\2_photos"
set "Fdesigns=%CD%\3_designs"
set "Freviews=%CD%\4_reviews"
set "Ffinal=%CD%\5_final"
set "$ext="
set "action=Cleaning"

:: CLEAN :: documents
set "$ext=.txt .doc .docx .xls .csv .ppt .pptx"
call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fdocs%"
cls
echo %action% project folder.

:: CLEAN :: images
set "$ext=.jpg .png .tiff .raw .nef .crw .dng"
:: for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%Fphotos%"
call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fphotos%"
cls
echo %action% project folder..
timeout 1 >nul

:: CLEAN :: designs
set "$ext=.psd .psb"
call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fdesigns%"
::for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%Fdesigns%\2_psd"
set "$ext=.ai .svg .svgz .esp"
call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fdesigns%"
::for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%Fdesigns%\1_ai"
set "$ext=.indd .idml" 
call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fdesigns%"
::for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%CD%\*%%a" "%CD%\%Fdesigns%\3_indd"
cls
echo %action% project folder...
timeout 1 >nul

cls
echo done.
timeout 2 >nul
:: skip over predefined subroutine(s) and return from script
goto :eof

:: Create a subroutine function loop : FOR , go through array file extentions and move to destination
:: FOR /F
:fMover
for %%a in (%~1) do move "%CD%\*%%~a" "%CD%\%~2"
echo %%a
timeout 1 >nul
:: return from subroutine
goto :eof
```

Resources:

- `call`  [a subroutine (:label)](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html);
- [`set` command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) (quotation to avoid all leading or trailing spaces);
- [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and `~` modifier;
- [`GOTO :eof` jump](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) to predefined `:eof` label will exit the current routine (one could use `exit /B` instead);
- note: using `::` pseudolabel instead of [`rem` comment command](http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html) could be harmful when used  within a bracketed code block.

Comment: See I was wondering about subroutines and if the returned back to the call which invoked them but found out that they don't through testing.JosefZ do you think it's better to modularize more complex operations and do batch to batch calls instead of building a single batch to handle the same type of operation?

Comment: It's your preference; modular approach (technique) is not bad or poor idea, imho. However, you could make your script simpler and more readable via omitting all `set` commands (or most of them) and pass straight literal values into procedure as follows (for instance): `call :fMover ".psd .psb"  "%CD%\3_designs"`

Comment: Alright so Josef I feel like I'm almost able to accomplish this the only problem is I don't think the for loop is iterating through the array like object which is storing the file extensions. I am able to print the first extension but that is it I researched and think a possible solution might come from Dir /b but not sure how to use with the for loop as instructed by ss64.com http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html (filenameset)